# Пытаюсь написать inline бота для Telegram 2.0, телеграм отвечает ok, но ничего не показывает в результатах

Tags: ruby, telegram-bot

Телеграм отвечает мне `{"ok"=>true, "result"=>true}` и даже показывает кнопку «перейти в приват», но не показывает мне никаких результатов в инлайн режиме. Кажется мне, что проблема в том, как я формирую `results`, но почему тогда я получаю ок, а не 400, может кто-то знает рабочий пример или понимает в чём проблема?
Вот кусок кода:

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
  bot.listen do |message|

    case message
    when Telegram::Bot::Types::Message
      puts "Message @#{message.from.username}: #{message.text}"
      bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "I am only inline bot for now" )
    when Telegram::Bot::Types::InlineQuery
      puts " InlineQuery @#{message.from.username}: #{message.query} and #{message.id}"

      results = [ JSON.parse('{"type":"article", "id":"0", "title":"Cool Blog", "message_text":"I am the author of this bot, please visit my blog"}'), JSON.parse('{"type":"article", "id":"1", "title":"Cool Blog", "message_text":"I am the author of this bot, please visit my blog"}')] 
      puts bot.api.answer_inline_query(inline_query_id: message.id, results: results, switch_pm_text:"PM me please", cache_time: 86400)
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: This site is for questions in Russian only. You can either translate the question or ask it at http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Спасибо, переписал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновите версию гема, текущая 0.5, заработает `gem install 'telegram-bot-ruby'`

Comment: напишите до какой версии точно